# Cannot connect Node to Mongodb

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

What are the possible explanations to why I cannot connect to local MongoDB using Node?
I tried using native driver.
Also tried using mongoose. Same result.... *(mongoose readyState stays at 2 forever).
Not connecting at all. But it is possible to create dbs and collections using compass or mongo console.  Works just fine that way.
Running the `App.js` doesn't. Any help please?

Node re-installing could help? Im con windows, by the way...
Windows 10, Node v12.18.0, Mongodb 4.2.8

```js
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
console.log("We are not connected yet");
// Connect to the db
MongoClient.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/exampleDb", function(err, db) {
  //its like never entering to callback!
  if (!err) {
    console.log("We are connected");
  }
  if (err) {
    console.log("Error is " + err); //never gets here, nothing printed
  }
});
```

And the console only says :

> We are not connected yet

Comment: can you pass the error and the code block?

Comment: There is no error. Simply, nothing happens, the console.log to say we are connected never triggers... but i'll try to edit and add the code, it is the basic one...

Comment: Is your mongoDB process running? if linux use sudo service mongod start

Comment: try console logging the `err` outside of the `if(!err)` to see the error

Comment: Try `console.log(err)` to see what error you're getting.

Comment: I did, nothing is printed. Besides, it skip that line. It skip the hole block inside callback

Comment: wrap everything in a try // catch block -- you have an uncaught error.

Answer (score 0):

What's your version of node.js?

From version 17 on the default DNS resolution switched from ipv4 to ipv6.
You may try to pass the 'ipv4' argument.

Check these out:

https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/NODE-4538

https://nodejs.org/api/net.html#class-netsocketaddress

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34121012)